# Bootstrap Responsive Utility Class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have 4 columns for large screens that are to go to 2 rows of 2 columns on medium screens. But then columns get pushed over and moved down with medium screens.

I know somehow a responsive utility class is supposed to fix it, just not sure how.

Here is my code

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply [clearfix](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css) in conjunction with a [utility class](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css). Since you're just collapsing everything on a `col-md-6`, apply `clearfix` after your second column (since you want two @ medium).

See working example Snippet.

```css
/*FOR DEMO ONLY*/

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="well">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="well">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="well">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="well">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @vanburen...that does work...but what's the well class?...was that just extra, or is it for something?

Comment: It just so it's easier to see what's happening (so there's a clear divide of columns for the example), nothing more.